# SQL server writes an entry to the backupset table after a restore?

Tags: sql-server

I’ve noticed that when doing a database restore, SQL Server writes an entry to the msdb.dbo.backupset table about the backup?

I can fully understand it writing an entry to the msdb.dbo.restorehistory table, I don’t understand why it would write an entry to the backupset table.

Is this normal?:
I've tested this on multiple versions with the same result.
It’s as if it does a RESTORE HEADERONLY on the .BAK file and inserts that exact line into the backupset table.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think,it should not log any records to `BackupSet` table..

From [MSDN](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186299(v=sql.110).aspx)..

> A backup set contains the backup from a single, successful backup operation.
>
> RESTORE, RESTORE FILELISTONLY, RESTORE HEADERONLY, and RESTORE VERIFYONLY statements operate on a single backup set within the media set on the specified backup device or devices.

and you are doing Restore